# Batch - type command that skips empty lines

Tags: types, batch-file

Is it possible to have the `type` command skip empty lines in a text file?

Or is there an alternate command that will print out the contents of a text file while skipping empty lines in that text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solution for [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
sed "/^$/d" file_with_empty_lines > file_without_empty_lines
```

or without external tools:

```
(for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("file_with_empty_lines") do echo(%%a)> file_without_empty_lines
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without 3rd party programs? I can't install any programs on my school network :P

Comment: I had to remove the "> file_without_empty_lines" because I just wanted it to display the text on screen, but apart from that, it works perfectly! You saved the day again Endoro :)